# Magento 2 :How to restrict add to cart quantity limit?

Tags: magento2

I want to set a restriction for add to cart

e.g customer only able to add 1 qty for a single product at a time.

I just want to set a limit on qty so the customer is not able to add more than 1 qty at a time.

Comment: Why it is negative marking ? please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Magento Backend and edit any item. There is one link available below `QTY` field **advanced inventory**. Click on that option. There is one text field available for it.

**Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart** you can uncheck `Use Config Settings` and set QTY there.

Save that product. That's it.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Nice!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

To configure Max and Min Qty in Shopping Cart settings you have to go to:

> Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options.

Check the setting there for Cart Qty settings as per your need. These settings can be allowed or disallowed from a checkbox in the product edit page in the **Advanced Inventory Section**.